# update object with SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have a method into my `Repository` class that receives a object that was not loaded from database but is populated with the right id and I want to update it into the database:

```
class Repository(object):
 def __init__(session):
  self.session = session

 def update(self, car):
  self.session.update(car)
```

There is no method `update` into `session`. Also if I use `add` method the record is not updated.

How can I update the object with SQLAlchemy?

Comment: Call self.session.commit()

Answer (score 1):

i found it out.
the right way to do it is to call `session.merge(car)`